# Checking if a vector can be eigenvector of an eigenvalue.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

An affine transformation is given by:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    3     & 4 & 8  \\
    -2   & -3 & 7  \\
   0  & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

The matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    3     & 4   \\
    -2   & -3   \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$
Has the eigenvalues $1,-1$. And the eigenvectors $(-2,1),(-1,1).$
I want to find the points $P$ so that $\overrightarrow{Pf(P)}$ is an eigenvector. I have calculated $\overrightarrow{Pf(P)}=(2x+4y+8,-2x-4y+7)$. Now I think I should see if this vector can be eigenvector of the eigenvalue $-1$ or $1$. How can I do that?

Comment: Does row 3 of the larger matrix mean that $z$ map to $z$? [could you spell out how a 3X3 matix produces an affine transformation?]

Comment: @coffeemath Use homogeneous coortdinates. Basically, the last column gives the translation part of the transformation. The form of the last row of the matrix indicates that it represents an affinity. If it were to have nonzero entries in any but the last column, it would represent a true projective transformation instead.

Comment: Any nonzero scalar multiple of the eigenvectors that you’ve found is also an eigenvector. You should be able to construct two systems of equations from that.

Comment: @amd How do I set up those two systems of equations?

Comment: You’ve got an expression for $w=\overrightarrow{Pf(P)}$ and know two independent eigenvectors $v_1$ and $v_2$. Introduce an unknown scalar $k$ and set $w$ equal to $kv_1$ and $kv_2$, respectively.

Comment: @amd Thank you, I found the points, they are on the line formed by $(1,5)+\langle(-2,1)\rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picking up where you left off, you have an explicit expression for $\overrightarrow{Pf(P)} = f(P)-P$ and two linearly independent eigenvectors $\mathbf v_1=(-2,1)^T$ and $\mathbf v_2=(-1,1)^T$. Recalling that any nonzero scalar multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector, this means that we must have $f(P)-P=\alpha \mathbf v_1$ or $f(P)-P=\beta \mathbf v_2$ for some non-zero scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Expanding the first equation produces the system $$\begin{align} 2x+4y+8 &= -2\alpha \\ -2x-4y+7 &= \alpha.\end{align}$$ Adding twice the second equation and dividing out a common factor of $2$ gives the equation $x+2y-11=0$. This line has $\mathbf v_1$ as a direction vector and, as you can verify for yourself, is mapped to itself by the transformation (I’ll come back to this point later). For $\mathbf v_2$ the corresponding system of equations is $$\begin{align} 2x+4y+8 &= -\beta \\ -2x-4y+7 &= \beta.\end{align}$$ This system is clearly inconsistent, so there are no points $P$ for which $f(P)-P$ lies in the span of $v_2$.

There’s a slightly different approach to this problem that highlights the geometric meaning of the condition to be satisfied. Write $f(P)=L(P)+\mathbf b$, where $L$ is the linear part of $f$, and let $\mathbf v$ be an eigenvector of $L$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. If $P$ satisfies $f(P)-P=\alpha\mathbf v$ for some $\alpha\ne0$, then $$\begin{align} f(P+t\mathbf v) - (P+t\mathbf v) &= L(P+t\mathbf v)+\mathbf b - P-t\mathbf v \\ &= L(P) + \lambda t\mathbf v + \mathbf b - P - t\mathbf v \\ &= f(P) - P + (\lambda-1) t\mathbf v \\ &= \alpha\mathbf v +(\lambda-1)t\mathbf v, \end{align}$$ which is also a scalar multiple of $\mathbf v$, so almost every point on the line $P+t\mathbf v$ also satisfies the condition. (If $P+t\mathbf v$ happens to be a fixed point of $f$, then technically it fails because $0$ is never an eigenvector.) However, the image of a point on this line is itself of the form $P+t\mathbf v$ and so lies on the line, therefore the line is mapped to itself by $f$. Hence, we are really looking for the invariant lines of $f$.

Working in homogeneous coordinates, if $M$ is the matrix that represents $f$, then the invariant lines of $f$ are the eigenvectors of $$M^{-T} = \begin{bmatrix}3&-2&0\\4&-3&0\\-52&37&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ By inspection, $(0,0,1)^T$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. This is the line at infinity, which is always mapped to itself by affine transformations. The remaining eigenvalues are those of the upper-right $2\times2$ submatrix, and are easily found to be $\pm1$. There are no other linearly independent eigenvectors of $1$, consistent with the calculation at top, and the usual methods produce $(1,2,-11)^T$ as an eigenvector of $-1$, which corresponds to the line $x+2y-11=0$, as the computation at the top also found.